# how to show a django ModelForm field as uneditable

Tags: python, django, forms, model, edit

taking my initial lessons with `django ModelForm` ,I wanted to give the user ,ability to edit an entry in a blog.The `BlogEntry` has a `date,postedTime, title and content`.I want to show the user an editform which shows all these fields,but with only `title and content as editable`. The `date and postedTime should be shown as uneditable`.

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True)
   date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
   postedTime = models.TimeField(null=True)

...
```

For adding an entry ,I use a ModelForm in the normal way..

```
class BlogEntryAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry
...
```

But how do I create the edit form?I want it to `show the date,postedTime as uneditable` (but still show them on the form) and let the user edit the `title and description`.

if I use,`exclude in class Meta` for date and postedTime,that will cause them not to appear on the form.So,how can I show them as uneditable?

```
class BlogEntryEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry
        ...?...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the form object, declare the attribute of the field as `readonly`:

```
form.fields['field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: what will happend if someone crafts a request to that form? editable=False is better?

Answer (score 3):

Is `date` field represent a date when the entry first created or when it was modified last time?  If first then use [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) option else use [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now).  That is:

```
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

will set `date` to now when entry will be created.

`auto_now_add` makes field uneditable.  For other cases use [`editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.editable) option to make any field uneditable.  For example

```
postedDate = models.TimeField(null=True, editable=False)
```

Also, likely you will add `posted` boolean field to `Entry` model, so it is convinient to set `auto_now` on `postedDate`.  It will set `postedDate` to now every time you modify a Entry including one when you set `posted` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it this way: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10514/
this implementation uses the data of model instance for all read-only fields and not the data obtained while processing the form

below the same code but using his example

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.utils import six
from django.utils.encoding import force_str

__all__ = (
    'ReadOnlyFieldsMixin',
    'new_readonly_form_class'
)


class ReadOnlyFieldsMixin(object):
    """Usage:
    class MyFormAllFieldsReadOnly(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, forms.Form):
        ...


    class MyFormSelectedFieldsReadOnly(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, forms.Form):
        readonly_fields = ('field1', 'field2')
        ...
    """
    readonly_fields = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.define_readonly_fields(self.fields)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, self).clean()

        for field_name, field in six.iteritems(self.fields):
            if self._must_be_readonly(field_name):
                cleaned_data[field_name] = getattr(self.instance, field_name)

        return cleaned_data

    def define_readonly_fields(self, field_list):

        fields = [field for field_name, field in six.iteritems(field_list)
                  if self._must_be_readonly(field_name)]

        map(lambda field: self._set_readonly(field), fields)

    def _all_fields(self):
        return not bool(self.readonly_fields)

    def _set_readonly(self, field):
        field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true'
        field.required = False

    def _must_be_readonly(self, field_name):
        return field_name in self.readonly_fields or self._all_fields()


def new_readonly_form_class(form_class, readonly_fields=()):
    name = force_str("ReadOnly{}".format(form_class.__name__))
    class_fields = {'readonly_fields': readonly_fields}
    return type(name, (ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, form_class), class_fields)
```

#### Usage:

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    postedTime = models.TimeField(null=True)


# all fields are readonly    
class BlogEntryReadOnlyForm(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry

# selected fields are readonly
class BlogEntryReadOnlyForm2(ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    readonly_fields = ('date', 'postedTime')
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry
```

#### or use the function

```
class BlogEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry

BlogEntryFormReadOnlyForm = new_readonly_form_class(BlogEntryForm, readonly_fields=('description', ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent any user from hacking the request:

```
self.fields['is_admin'].disabled = True
```

Custom form example:

```
class MemberShipInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_admin = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MemberShipInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'instance' in kwargs and kwargs['instance'].is_group_creator:
            self.fields['is_admin'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
        model = MemberShip
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score -4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields),

```
class BlogEntryEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = BlogEntry
    readonly_fields = ['date','postedTime']
```

Comment: Just a question about the documention. It says `Any fields in this option (which should be a list or tuple) will display its data as-is and non-editable`. I've tried this but I can still click on the textfield and type in stuff into it. How does it actually work?

Comment: Is this possible for a ModelForm?I think the 'readonly_fields' is specific to ModelAdmin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: i think readonly_fields is admin specific and also introduced in django 1.2